# Allocate exception for servlet - Spring

Tags: spring, exception, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to resolve the following issue(exception is listed below).

I also referred to "[Servlet : Allocate exception for serlvet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366201/servlet-severe-allocate-exception-for-servlet)". Considering cleaning of directory (build issue) will help I deleted the the tmp folder in .metadata, which contains the project, but still the things are not working.

I have the following libraries (commons-logging.jar , spring.jar , spring-context.jar, spring-web.jar, spring-webmvc.jar) in WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
EVERE: Allocate exception for servlet HomeServlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:932)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:297)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: If you JARs are named the way you mention, what kind of version are they? I think that Spring's artifacts are always `{name}-{version}.jar`. And by the way "cleaning" in Eclipse does not mean deleting something manually, but cleaning via "Project > Clean" and "*server* > Clean...".

Comment: Those are 2.5 version libraries.I think its the issue with the runtime configuration for some reason it is not able to find the libraries.